# Combobox cancel dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've got a combobox that opens a new form window with a datagridview, and I want the users to choose the items through that datagridview rather than through the combobox. I've got this code to achieve that:

```
    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        valSel.incBox = (ComboBox)sender;            
        valSel.Show();
        if (this.comboBox1.DroppedDown)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
            SendMessage(this.comboBox1.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

As you see I'm also trying to hide the dropdown of the combobox but it isn't working. I assume it's because the combobox hasn't actually "dropped down" yet, so that part of the code is never run. 
Is there an event or something I can cell when the combobox has fully "dropped down" so i can send the message to close it again?

Comment: Can't you set the `Enabled` property of the comboBox to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply set the height of the `ComboBox` to something really small. Last time I looked at it, this determined the height of the popup part (the actual height of the control is determined by the UI/font size).

The more elegant way, however, would be using a custom control that just mimics the appearance of dropdown boxes (I'm rather sure that can be done some easy way).

Comment: +1 for using a different control.  Combobox is obviously not the right solution here.  A Label with a button next to it wrapped up in a user control would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

In comboBox1.Enter set the focus to a different control if condition is met.

```
 private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = false;
            comboBox2.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Select a list first");
            comboBox2.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create a KeyPress event on ComboBox from the properties.
2) write code

`private void cmbClientId_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        { 
            ((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = false; 
        }`